# Read ImageJ XY coordinates file into matlab

Tags: matlab, imagej

I am trying to read an ImageJ XY coordinates file (attached) using the code below but I get a strange output. Any idea what I did wrong?

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
imgMatrix = readmatrix("E:/fd1.txt"); 
imgMatrix(:,3) = []
x=imgMatrix(:,1);y=imgMatrix(:,2);
BW = poly2mask(x,y,ceil(max(y)) ,ceil(max(x)));
imshow(BW);
```

Original image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

fd1.txt file:
https://mega.nz/file/vE0SxDgb#rQuWCsH8H2fYvuzGTSMgjyMMdyZGfQYMhLJ3zdXcJB4

Thanks a lot

Comment: The text-file with the coordinates is no longer accessible.

Comment: The new link works! How did you export the coordinates and values from ImageJ?

Comment: I would suggest not providing text files in a dowload, but as text, in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I have no experience with *MATLAB* but let me explain a bit the format *ImageJ* uses, if you export values per "Analyze >> Tools >> Save XY Coordinates...".

If, like in the case in question, the background of an 8bit gray-value image is black (zero), I would first invert the image (important!) and set the background value in the "Save XY Coordinates"-dialog to zero, as well as check "Invert y coordinates off".

In the following I shall provide an *ImageJ*-macro that indirectly explains the structure of the data by reconstructing the image from the data that has to be saved with suffix ".tsv" not ".txt". Open this data file in *ImageJ* first and then run the macro:

```
requires("1.54g");
x=Table.getColumn("C1");
y=Table.getColumn("C2");
v=Table.getColumn("C3");
Array.getStatistics(x,mi,xMax);
Array.getStatistics(y,mi,yMax);
newImage("Reconstruction","8-bit black",xMax+1,yMax+1,1);
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      setPixel(x[i],y[i],v[i]);
run("Invert");
exit();
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks. I followed your instructions but I think it is more Matlab issue.

Comment: Sure, but you need to understand the organisation of the data you are exporting, in order to finally import the data correctly. The data exported from ImageJ in the described fashion is not as a 2D array. if you prefer 2D array data, then you need to export it from ImageJ by "Image >> Transform >> Image to Results" and save the resulting table e.g. as a text-file.

Comment: True, but I focus on the outline not all the image array.

Comment: If you are interested in the outline and if the image is binary-valued, I recommend to make a selection (Edit >> Selection >> Create Selection) and then to export the two arrays that are returned by "getSelectionCoordinates(xpoints, ypoints)". "Image >> Transform >> Image to Results" doesn't give you the outline but all of the object coordinates with values > background.

Comment: Thanks for the ImageJ help, highly appreciated. More and more I think it is a Matlab issue

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you like to change platforms. Are you sure the operations you intend to perform in MatLab can't be performed by ImageJ?

Answer (score 0):

Below please find an ImageJ-macro that saves the outline coordinates of a binary-valued image:

```
requires("1.54g");
run("Input/Output...", "jpeg=80 gif=-1 file=.txt");
run("Create Selection");
getSelectionCoordinates(xpoints, ypoints);
Array.show(xpoints, ypoints);
saveAs("text");
exit();
```